# Regular Expression to match everything that appears before a colon?

Tags: regex

I need to remove some data from an RSS feed.

It's everything that appears before a **:** and also preferably the space that appears just after the **:**

Example:

**Hello :** Charlie wants to know how to delete everything behind him from behind the colon and one space in front. I will always have this question mark on the end?

Where the : and hello would be matched but not the "Charlie said hello"

Thanks to all who have this wonderful knowledge and take time to reply.

Comment: I see bold. Is the content HTML?

Comment: When you say "everything before a :", do you mean everything before the *first* :, or the last?

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
^[^:]+:\s*
```

instead of

```
^.+:\s*
```

This is an example of it working:

```
perl -le 'my $string = q{Foo : bar baz}; $string =~ s{^[^:]+:\s*}{}; print $string;'
```

And I recommended the first one over the second to avoid greediness issues:

```
perl -le 'my $string = q{Foo : bar: baz}; $string =~ s{^[^:]+:\s*}{}; print $string;'
```

To see the greediness issues I mentioned:

```
perl -le 'my $string = q{Foo : bar baz}; $string =~ s{^.+:\s*}{}; print $string;'
perl -le 'my $string = q{Foo : bar: baz}; $string =~ s{^.+:\s*}{}; print $string;'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
^[^:]+:\s?
```

The trailing `\s?` will match a space following the colon, but not require it.

I agree with **@gpojd**; you should use a negative character class to avoid greediness issues if there are colons in the payload.

Comment: Why `\s?` - `.` will match space (not line breaks though).

Answer (score 1):

You can use just:
`^.*:`

This matches:

`Hello :` Charlie wants to know how to delete everything behind him from behind the colon and one space in front. I will always have this question mark on the end?

Answer (score 1):

Something like `^.*: *` should work well. This matches from the beginning of the line up to the colon and any spaces after it.